# How to perform multiple Http requests (Tasks) in bulk in Elm lang

Tags: http, task, elm

I want to load user profile before rendering something into the page but the whole user profile is composed of different parts that are loaded by multiple HTTP requests.

So far I'm loading user profile in sequence (one by one)

```
type alias CompanyInfo = 
  { name: String
  , address: ...
  , phone: String
  , ...
  }

type alias UserProfile = 
  { userName: String
  , companyInfo: CompanyInfo
  , ... 
  }

Cmd.batch
  [ loadUserName userId LoadUserNameFail LoadUserNameSuccess
  , loadCompanyInfo userId LoadCompanyInfoFail LoadCompanyInfoSuccess
  ...
  ]
```

But that's not very effective. Is there a simple way how to perform a bunch of Http requests and return just one complete value?

Something like this

```
init = 
    (initialModel, loadUserProfile userId LoadUserProfileFail LoadUserProfileSuccess)

....
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can achieve this using [`Task.map2`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Task#map2):

**Edit: Updated to Elm 0.18**

```elm
Task.attempt LoadUserProfile <|
    Task.map2 (\userName companyInfo -> { userName = userName, companyInfo = companyInfo })
        (Http.get userNameGetUrl userDecoder |> Http.toTask)
        (Http.get companyInfoGetUrl companyInfoDecoder |> Http.toTask)
```

You can then get rid of the individual LoadUserName... and LoadCompanyInfo... Msgs. In Elm 0.18, the need for separate Fail and Succeed `Msgs` is addressed by `Task.attempt` expecting a `Result Error Msg` type, so that `LoadUserProfile` is defined like this:

```elm
type Msg
    = ...
    | LoadUserProfile (Result Http.Error UserProfile)
```

`map2` will only succeed once both tasks succeed. It will fail if any of the tasks fail.

Comment: Worth noting that these network requests will run sequentially; they _won't_ be concurrent.

Comment: Is there a way to do this that _is_ concurrent?

Comment: Use `Cmd.batch`  to run Tasks concurrently. Note that they will have no relation to each other, so any dependencies between results will have to be handled by you in your `update` function.

Comment: Thanks, @mLuby. I've updated the answer for Elm 0.18

Comment: @ChadGilbert Where is it documented that `Cmd.batch` will run the Tasks concurrently?

Comment: I think you mean in *parallel*, as explained in the docs, things can be done sequentially but concurrently.

Comment: The method `Http.toTask` does not exist anymore it appears, it might be good to replace it by using `Http.task` instead of `Http.get`
.