# How to batch multiple http calls together?

Tags: elm, elm-architecture

I have a report which I'm using as a basis to perform a number of Http calls to get details for each row.

```
LoadReport ->
    ( model
    , Http.toTask (loadReport model.token model.page)
        |> Task.andThen
            (\report ->
                Task.map (addProductDetailsResultsToReport report) (Task.sequence (prepareRequests model.token report))
            )
        |> Task.map filterOnlyMissingBarcodes
        |> Task.attempt ProductData
    )
```

The calls are sequenced and perform one after another which is very slow as I need to perform 20 calls in a row. I would like to do something analogues to JavaScript

```
 Promise.all(prepareRequests)
```

I used to have them being processed using Cmd.Batch but then I couldn't find a way to know when the whole batch is finished loading, I need to load another batch if there are not enough rows on the screen.

Comment: Can you use `Process.spawn` to create concurrent calls for each row?
https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Process

Comment: The problem with Process.spawn is that I cannot get the data from it.

Comment: Try with https://stackoverflow.com/a/39392952/1262904

Comment: @victorhazbun This is not concurrent AFAIR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the solution already posted by Murph is correct.  The following code is an example that demonstrates that solution by first getting a collection of photos from flickr and then getting captions for all those photos by batching a bunch of http get tasks.  Two lists are maintained in the model - untitled photos and titled photos.  As the responses to the http gets come in, the appropriate photo is added to titled photos with the title assigned.

In this example the code can tell that all the gets have been responded to when the length of the titled list is the same as the length of the untitled list but it could just as easily have been done by removing photos from the untitled list until it is empty.

[Here's a working demo](https://dc25.github.io/stackoverflow__how-to-batch-multiple-http-calls-together/)

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, div, text)
import Html.Attributes as HA
import Http
import Json.Decode as DC
import Svg
import Svg.Attributes as SA
import Task


type Msg
    = SetPhotos (Result Http.Error (List Photo))
    | SetDescription (Result Http.Error ( String, String ))


main : Program () Model Msg
main =
    Browser.element
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = \m -> Sub.none
        }


type alias Model =
    Result Http.Error
        { untitled : List Photo
        , titled : List Photo
        }


decodeUser : DC.Decoder String
decodeUser =
    DC.at [ "user", "id" ] DC.string


type alias Photo =
    { id : String
    , secret : String
    , server : String
    , farm : Int
    , description : Maybe String
    }



-- Create a Photo record from info retrieved from flickr api.
-- Get description later


initPhoto : String -> String -> String -> Int -> Photo
initPhoto id sec ser farm =
    Photo id sec ser farm Nothing


decodePhotoList : DC.Decoder (List Photo)
decodePhotoList =
    DC.list <|
        DC.map4 initPhoto
            (DC.at [ "id" ] DC.string)
            (DC.at [ "secret" ] DC.string)
            (DC.at [ "server" ] DC.string)
            (DC.at [ "farm" ] DC.int)



-- Decode photos from "flickr.people.getPublicPhotos" request.


decodePhotos : DC.Decoder (List Photo)
decodePhotos =
    DC.at [ "photos", "photo" ] decodePhotoList



-- Decode descripion of photo from "flickr.photos.getInfo" request.


decodePhotoDescription : DC.Decoder String
decodePhotoDescription =
    DC.at [ "photo", "description", "_content" ] DC.string



-- api key from flickr.  Anyone who clones this project should
-- get their own api key.


apiKey : String
apiKey =
    "e9d3fdd5c2e26f9ebd13f4983cf727db"


flickrRestServices : String
flickrRestServices =
    "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?"


noJsonCallback : String
noJsonCallback =
    "&format=json&nojsoncallback=1"


userUrl : String -> String
userUrl name =
    flickrRestServices
        ++ "&method=flickr.people.findByUserName"
        ++ "&api_key="
        ++ apiKey
        ++ "&username="
        ++ name
        ++ noJsonCallback


publicPhotosUrl : String -> String
publicPhotosUrl uid =
    flickrRestServices
        ++ "&method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos"
        ++ "&api_key="
        ++ apiKey
        ++ "&user_id="
        ++ uid
        ++ noJsonCallback


photoInfoUrl : String -> String
photoInfoUrl photo =
    flickrRestServices
        ++ "&method=flickr.photos.getInfo"
        ++ "&api_key="
        ++ apiKey
        ++ "&photo_id="
        ++ photo
        ++ noJsonCallback



-- Cmd to get photo description from flickr.
-- Package results as SetDescription message.
-- Save the photo id with Task.map to apply the description to the right photo


setDescriptionCmd : Photo -> Cmd Msg
setDescriptionCmd dp =
    case dp.description of
        Nothing ->
            Task.attempt SetDescription (Task.map (\s -> ( dp.id, s )) <| Http.toTask <| Http.get (photoInfoUrl dp.id) decodePhotoDescription)

        Just des ->
            Cmd.none



-- Cmd to get users public photos from flickr.
-- Package results as SetPhotos message.


getPhotosCmd : String -> Cmd Msg
getPhotosCmd name =
    let
        req =
            Http.get (userUrl name) decodeUser

        userTask =
            Http.toTask req

        publicPhotosTask uid =
            Http.toTask (Http.get (publicPhotosUrl uid) decodePhotos)

        userPhotosTask =
            userTask |> Task.andThen publicPhotosTask
    in
    Task.attempt SetPhotos userPhotosTask


init : () -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init _ =
    ( Ok
        { untitled = []
        , titled = []
        }
    , getPhotosCmd "elmDemo" -- flickr user name
    )



-- UPDATE


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        SetPhotos (Ok photos) ->
            ( Ok
                { untitled = photos
                , titled = []
                }
            , Cmd.batch <| List.map setDescriptionCmd photos
            )

        SetPhotos (Err e) ->
            ( Err e
            , Cmd.none
            )

        -- Update description of the photo with matching id.
        SetDescription (Ok ( photoId, desc )) ->
            case model of
                Ok photos ->
                    let
                        justTitled =
                            photos.untitled
                                |> List.filter (\ph -> ph.id == photoId)
                                |> List.map (\ph -> { ph | description = Just desc })
                        newTitled = photos.titled ++ justTitled 
                        newPhotos = { photos | titled = newTitled }
                    in
                    ( Ok newPhotos
                    , if
                        List.length newPhotos.titled
                            == List.length newPhotos.untitled
                      then
                        Cmd.none -- Could do something else here.

                      else
                        Cmd.none
                    )

                Err e ->
                    ( Err e
                    , Cmd.none
                    )

        SetDescription (Err e) ->
            ( Err e
            , Cmd.none
            )



-- Compute a photo URL from a Photo record.
-- per: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html


photoUrl : Photo -> String
photoUrl ps =
    "https://farm"
        ++ String.fromInt ps.farm
        ++ ".staticflickr.com/"
        ++ ps.server
        ++ "/"
        ++ ps.id
        ++ "_"
        ++ ps.secret
        ++ "_b.jpg"



-- show an image and description if available.


viewPhoto : Photo -> Html Msg
viewPhoto ps =
    div
        [ HA.style "height" "20%"
        , HA.style "width" "20%"
        , HA.style "margin" "0"
        ]
        [ div
            [ HA.style "height" "90%"
            , HA.style "width" "100%"
            , HA.style "margin" "0"
            ]
            [ Svg.svg
                [ SA.version "1.1"
                , SA.width "100%"
                , SA.height "100%"
                , SA.viewBox "-1 -0.6 2 1.2"
                , SA.preserveAspectRatio "none"
                ]
                [ Svg.image
                    [ SA.xlinkHref (photoUrl ps)
                    , SA.x "-1"
                    , SA.y "-0.6"
                    , SA.width "2"
                    , SA.height "1.2"
                    ]
                    []
                ]
            ]
        , div
            [ HA.style "height" "10%"
            , HA.style "width" "100%"
            , HA.style "margin" "0"
            ]
            [ div
                [ HA.style "text-align" "center" ]
                [ text <| Maybe.withDefault "" ps.description ]
            ]
        ]



-- Draw an image or display the reason the image is not available.


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    case model of
        Err s ->
            text "Error: "

        Ok photos ->
            div []
                [ div [] [ text "UNTITLED" ]
                , div [] (List.map viewPhoto photos.untitled)
                , div [] [ text "TITLED" ]
                , div [] (List.map viewPhoto photos.titled)
                ]
```

Comment: ( Ok newPhotos
    ....
I find this part a bit confusing, what does it mean? 
The Ok part is throwing me off, don't get why we are returning that instead of a model

--- 
Ah didn't notice that the model itself is Http.Result. I think I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Random thought:

Given that you will get a response back for each call you can keep track of the calls received by creating a collection of expected responses before calling batch and then removing the appropriate item from the collection each time a response is received.

At the point at which that collection is empty you've received all the responses and can fire off the next batch.

There are any number of variations on this pattern that should achieve the desired result. (And probably other patterns that would work just as well.)

Comment: Just read my mind :) 
I was trying to create a structure like that in Elm for the last 20 minutes. Not much luck so far.

Comment: rather than removing elements from a collection, just update a record with custom types for your responses using `Maybe a`. If your record fields are all `Just a` then the batch is done.

Comment: @MatthewStevenson it is, by definition, an arbitrary collection of at least somewhat arbitrary values - so it has to be something that is added to or removed from. I don't know what would be idiomatic, but my feeling is that creating (say) a set of identifiers, doing a remove from that set, for the identifier, upon receiving a response event and then acting on whether the set "isEmpty" is about as straightforward as you can get?